# Trouble returning simple array: "Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined "

Tags: javascript

In this case I would expect the log to output `anything` for `metaData[price]` but instead I have an error telling me `metaData[price]` is not defined.

```
function getMetaData(item) {
    var metaData = new Object();
    metaData[name] = $(item).siblings('.itemModalHolder').find('.item_name').text();
    metaData[price] = "anything";
    console.log(metaData[price]);
    return metaData;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to quote the object keys:

```
metaData['name'] = $(item).siblings('.itemModalHolder').find('.item_name').text();
metaData['price'] = "anything";
```

or the much cleaner syntax

```
metaData.name  = $(item).siblings('.itemModalHolder').find('.item_name').text();
metaData.price = "anything";
```